# GAE Python - Task to save CSV to same Blobstore element daily

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv, blobstore

I've been reading through some similar questions but wasn't able to find an answer that I can implement. I am using Google App Engine and doing a simple CSV export using unicodecsv, which works fine. This export is supposed to run daily and save the result as the same Blobstore item every time, so it can be retrieved from the same URL.

I know that this is not the initial intention of Blobstore items, but I also read some articles that got it working. Unforuntately since I am not such an experienced programmer, I wasn't able to use any of it for my situation. Would be great if someone could give me some input on how to realize this.

```
class ShopExport(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    shops = Shop.all()
    self.response.headers[str('Content-Type')] = str('application/csv')
    self.response.headers[str('Content-Disposition')] = str('attachment; filename="shops.csv"')
    writer = unicodecsv.writer(self.response.out, encoding='utf-8')
    writer.writerow(["id", "name", "domain", "category", "deeplink"])
    for shop in shops:
      writer.writerow(["'"+shop.keyname+"'", "'"+shop.name+"'", "'"+shop.url+"'", "'"+shop.category+"'", "'"+shop.url_aff+"'"])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Tim pointed out you cannot overwrite blobstore entity, but you may create a new one every time and remember the key to serve the new entity:

```
class BlobKey(db.Model) :
    blob_key = db.StringProperty()
```

then, in a cron handler you may:

```
blob_key = BlobKey.all().get()
blob = blobstore.get(blob_key)
if blob : blob.delete()
db.delete( blob_key )    # you don't need it anymore

file_name = files.blobstore.create( mime_type = 'text/csv')
with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
    f.write( your_content )

files.finalize(file_name)
blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)

BlobKey( blob_key = str(blob_key) ).put()   # save the new key
```

and, finally, when you serve your file (in a `BlobstoreDownloadHandler`) you do just:

```
blob_key = BlobKey.all().get()
if blobstore.get(blob_key):
    self.send_blob(blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key),
        content_type = 'text/csv', save_as=True)    # False to mangle file name
else:
    self.error(404)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not overwrite a blob store entity, only delete it. You have no control over the blob store key, so you will have to keep/manage the URL in yourapp with a redirect to the current blob store URL.  As for writing to the blob store, have a look at the file api

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore

Comment: Thanks Tim, the article was very helpful.